# Swap alternate elements in an array using recursion?

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion, swap, static-variables

I wrote the below code to **swap alternate elements in an array** {eg. (1,2,3,4,5)-->(2,1,4,3,5) }. I wanted to try it using recursion.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void print(int *a, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

void swap(int *x, int *y) //swaps two elements
{
    int temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}

void swapAlter(int *a, int n) //swaps elements in an array
{
    static int i;
    if (i >= n - 1)
        return;
    else
    {
        swap(&a[i], &a[i + 1]);
        i += 2;
        swapAlter(a, n);
    }
}

//driver code
int main()
{

    int a[] = {7, 4, 5, 6, 21, 2, 9};
    int size = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
    cout << "normal array--> ";
    print(a, size);
    cout << endl;
    swapAlter(a, size);
    cout << "updated array--> ";
    print(a, size);
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

the above code works just fine but i was wondering if there is a **recursive** approach possible *(i'm sure it definitely is)* to do the same **without using static variable**.

Comment: You can make `i` a function parameter instead of a static variable. But more idiomatic would be to alter `a` and `n` on each recursive call and then you wouldn't need `i` at all.

Comment: You can either pass the current position to `swapAlter` or increment the pointer `a` as you don't need to access the elements in the beginning anymore. Pass `a+n` as second element and once you reach that address you know you are done.

Comment: Concerning the static variable as already said you can pass it as parameter. Otherwise the code is already recursive as you are calling swapAlter() function recursively.

Comment: Additionally, please check `std::swap()`. It does exactly what you implemented in you function by hand.

Comment: Sure.  `void SwapAlter(int *a, int n) {if (n <= 1) return; swap(a, a+1); SwapAlter(a + 2, n - 2);}`

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, I would suggest to pass a modified `start` as an offset into the array in order to get rid of the static variable `i`. I would also replace the `swap` with the built-in `std::swap` version.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> // for std::swap
using namespace std;

void print(int *a, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

void swapAlter(int *start, int *end) //swaps elements in an array
{
    if (start+1 < end)
    {
        swap(*start, *(start+1));
        swapAlter(start+2, end);
    }
}

//driver code
int main()
{

    int a[] = {7, 4, 5, 6, 21, 2, 9};
    int size = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
    cout << "normal array--> ";
    print(a, size);
    cout << endl;
    swapAlter(a, a+size);
    cout << "updated array--> ";
    print(a, size);
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```